# Mod rewrite regex htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been using `mod_rewrite` in order to block some user agents but now, I'm getting an 500 Error and error_log:

```
/var/www/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression
```

I think that my regex is ok, and the issue is the `RewriteCond` is too long.

Example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (UserAgent1|UserAgent2|UserAgent3)[NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [G]
</IfModule>
```

So I've tried to add the new user agents to a new line but it didn't work either.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (UserAgent1|UserAgent2|UserAgent3)[NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [G]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (UserAgent4|UserAgent5|UserAgent6)[NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [G]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you not need a space before the [NC] ?

Answer (score 1):

I use these rules. Keep it simple...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} almaden [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Anarchie [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ASPSeek [OR]
...
RewriteRule ^.* - [G]
```

I use `RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]` as in [Ultimate htaccess Blacklist](https://perishablepress.com/ultimate-htaccess-blacklist/). It is a great resource!